# keep getting an error when i try to run node boilerplate

Tags: javascript

The following code produces this type error when run with Node

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type
> string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received
> undefined

It works when run with an undisclosed older version. Please help

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const folderName = process.argv[2] || 'Project'

fs.mkdirSync(folderName);
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/index.html`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/app.js`)
fs.writeFileSync(`${folderName}/styles.css`)
```

Comment: [fs.writeFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) requires at least two parameters, `file` and `data`. You are only passing one

Comment: [`writeFileSync` requires a second argument](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-writefilesync-method/) - the data.